Do Kashmiri Shaivas believe in the Shiva Purana and its stories? And what is their position on Shaiva Upanishads?
Do Kashmiri Shaivas believe in the Shiva Purana and its stories?
The tales such as Shiva appearing as a fire pillar (lingam) etc etc.
Did Trika Acharyas mention these events in there works somewhere?
And what is their stance on Shaiva Upanishads (especially those that are included in the major principle Upanishads like Kaivalya Upanishads)?

I doubt. Trika is very particular to adhyatma and its methods.

I think Kashmir shaiva acharyas did quote from Upanishads.
